# ArgumentError and Internal Server Error 500 has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, internal-server-error

I am creating a form and wanted to implement many-to-many-associations. The first one was working fine, but after I added two more, I got this Internal Server Error.
Even if I delete the has_many code snippets, the site still won't work. Where is my error?

```
Started GET "/clinics" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Jul 07 20:25:32 +0200 2012

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)):


Error during failsafe response: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:204:in `initialize'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:81:in `rescue_action_locally
'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:69:in `render_exception'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  c:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'


Started GET "/clinics" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Jul 07 20:51:56 +0200 2012

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)):
```

I'll post all my models:

```
class Clinic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :born_on, :clinic, :menopause, :menodate, :pregnancies, :preg_nr, :hormones, :carcinomes, :who_carci, :digni, :size, :calci, :makro, :mikro, :preresult, :enr, :operation_ids, :mamma, :resection, :lkdissektion_ids, :other_diss, :faszie, :pectoralis, :localization_ids

  has_many :loca_hms
  has_many :localizations, :through => :loca_hms

  has_many :op_hms
  has_many :operations, :through => :op_hms

  has_many :lkdiss_hms
  has_many :lkdissektions, :through => :lkdiss_hms
end
```

```
class Operation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :op_hms
  has_many :clinics, :through => :op_hms
end
```

```
class OpHm < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :clinic_id, :operation_id

  belongs_to :clinic
  belongs_to :operation
end
```

```
class Localization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :loca_hms
  has_many :clinics, :through => :loca_hms
end
```

```
class LocaHm < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :clinic_id, :localization_id

  belongs_to :clinic
  belongs_to :localization
end
```

```
class Lkdissektion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :lkdiss_hms
  has_many :clinics, :through => :lkdiss_hms
end
```

```
class LkdissHm < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :clinic_id, :lkdissektion_id

  belongs_to :clinic
  belongs_to :lkdissektion
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the rake db:migrate command screwed something up. I had to drop my whole db and db:create / db:migrate again. now it's working like a charm !